# Retrieve Image from URL in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have an image in my Silverlight application and I want to source to come from a url. I create a URI and then create a bitmapimage and set it's urisource to this uri. I think set the image's source to the bitmapimage. When I do this, in debug mode, I can see all the properties of the images source, but it does not display on the ui. How do I bind an image's source to a url in silverlight? (note: the url is that of a png image)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be caused by cross site scripting limitation.

İf so, you can develop a proxy handler (ashx) on your web project that xap hosted. This handler can take outer url as get/post parameter and download this image on server and writes to response as binary to allow your silverlight project to get it from its origiated url.